# The default colors in XCalc are misleading

Tags: 22.04, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on an HP/Intel box and the default button colors in the XCalc calculator app are confusing. Most of the buttons are light blue but there are 12 buttons in the middle (some functions and some numbers) that are white and five buttons on the right side that are tan. This makes using the calculator confusing.

[image: XCalc with incorrect colors]

I checked the `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XCalc-color` file and it does not match what is displayed.

Is there a way to fix XCalc's colors?

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of open-source software, I spent some time working
on the `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XCalc-color` file and customized the
colors for each button, mapping different colors to various
function groups. Here is an image of the results:

[image: improved button colors for xcalc]

For anyone who is interested, the modified `XCalc-color` file is shown below. Note that the changes only apply to the TI mode, not the HP mode. The new file is available here: https://www.solorb.com/software/XCalc-color

Comment: Great color scheme! 

Answer (score 1):

The part of the [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xcalc) for this application that affects its customisation is reproduced below:

> ### Customization
>
> The application class name is XCalc.
>
> *xcalc* has an enormous application defaults file which specifies the
> position, label, and function of each key on the calculator. It also
> gives translations to serve as keyboard accelerators. Because these
> resources are not specified in the source code, you can create a
> customized calculator by writing a private application defaults file,
> using the Athena Command and Form widget resources to specify the size
> and position of buttons, the label for each button, and the function
> of each button.
>
> The foreground and background colors of each calculator key can be
> individually specified. For the TI calculator, a classical color
> resource specification might be:
>
> XCalc.ti.Command.background: gray50
> XCalc.ti.Command.foreground: white
>
> For each of buttons 20, 25, 30, 35, and 40, specify:
> XCalc.ti.button20.background: black
> XCalc.ti.button20.foreground: white
>
> For each of buttons 22, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 32, 33, 34, 37, 38, and
> 39:
> XCalc.ti.button22.background: white
> XCalc.ti.button22.foreground: black